# International (ex-US) ETFs with low exposure to financial sector?

Tags: investing, stocks, etf, asset-allocation

I've noticed that many international ETFs (especially emerging market funds) have a large stake in the financial sector. Are there any ETFs that de-emphasize financials?

Conversely, are there any ETFs that *only* target international financial stocks (which I could then sell short in order to achieve my desired allocation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a European financials ETF to short, you could take a look at the iShares EURO STOXX Banks, which is traded on a a few German stock exchanges (Frankfurt etc.):

[iShares Euro Stoxx Banks Website](http://de.ishares.com/en/rc/products/EXX1)

You find its current holdings here: [holdings](http://de.ishares.com/en/rc/products/EXX1/holdings).

Answer (score 1):

Another European financial ETF that you could sell short is the [iShares MSCI Europe Financials Sector Index Fund (EUFN)](http://us.ishares.com/product_info/fund/overview/EUFN.htm). It's traded on American exchanges, so it should be easier to access if you're in the United States. It is a relatively low-volume issue, however, so it may be difficult to locate shares to short, and the bid/ask spread could be a significant factor.